# How can I use PHP files as views in Durandal?

Tags: durandal

My problem is I want to integrate Durandal witha Wordpress site yet Durandal expects HTML files as views. How can this be changed to use PHP files?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. A php script generates dynamic HTML files on the server. You would just need to generate HTML that is valid within the context of Durandal.

The strategy is similar to using Durandal with ASP.Net, which would be a good place to start looking for tutorials.

Comment: The really vague. Please don't try to answer unless you can give some example code or a link to a page that does. Thank you.

Comment: Your question wasn't "please show me an example of." It was "can I do." The answer is yes.

Comment: Let's add the word 'how' then.